# Как реализовать AST в C++?

Tags: c++, парсер, компилятор, дерево

Мне нужно написать AST на C++ для собственного парсера. Написал примерно такую структуру:

```
class Node {
    TokenType type;
public:
    virual TokenType get_token();

};

class Statment : public Node {
    Statment* stmt;
public:
    virtual TokenType get_token();
};

class VarAssign : public Statment{
   std::string name;
   Expression* rval;;
public:
    virtual TokenType get_token();
};

class Expression : public Statment{
   Expression* expr1;
   Expression* expr2;
   ExprType t;
public:
    virtual TokenType get_token();
};

class NumberConst : public Expression {
   int val;
public:    
   void TokenType get_token();
   void int get_val();

 };
```

В main у меня такой код:

```
Statment* s = parseStmt();
```

В s->stmt у меня может быть `VarAssign`  `Expression`  или другие Statment классы, которые я не указал для простоты примера. В зависимости от того какой это будет класс, мне нужно вызывать разные методы. Как примерно это реализовать? И вообще я в правильном направлении иду к реализации AST, или это нужно делать по-другому?

Спасибо.

Comment: А насколько вы опытны чтобы самостоятельно реализовать `ast`? Это очень сложная задача, другое дело работа обход уже существующего `ast`. Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, я пишу компилятор. Не вижу ничего такого сложного в реализации AST для несложной структуры кода. Раньше я это делал в java, но я использовал только класс `Node` с полями `Node left, mid, right`, `Type t`

Comment: в таком случае советую использовать визитера для обхода нод

Comment: ну а вообще я все же бы посоветовал использовать `llvm` для создания компилятора - ничего лучше еще не придумали

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, я пишу компилятор с целью обучения, понять как он работает, поэтому пишу всё сам. Для обхода нод нужно сначала их построить.  Есть вариант  делать cast в тот тип, токен которого я получил от get_token().

Comment: @VitaliyShvets - не имеет значения, делается компилятор или нет, подходы одни и те же. Никто не мешает сделать функцию, которая принимает объект по указателю и сделать перегрузки для различных наследников. И теперь можно просто вызывать функцию, передавая туда ноду, а компилятор сам сделает код для выбора правильной перегрузки.Посмотрите на [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), который в данном случае очень хорошо подходит (а у него есть ещё [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), который решит ещё ряд задач)

Comment: @VitaliyShvets я вас не понимаю: в вопросе вы хотите вызывать разные методы у нод разных типов, но в комменте пишите, что: их нужно сначала построить... В чем у вас конкретно проблема?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, проблема в вызове методов, просто я не правильно понял ваш комментарий об обходе нод. Обязательно почитаю о визитере. Спасибо

Comment: нуда... обход AST — хрестоматийная мотивация для применения посетителя...